# If no database info, return a variable to be used to create a note about no data

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I'm working on a php function at the moment and I've run into a bit of bother.

At the moment I am using a function on a php page that goes like this:

```
get_Properties($currUser);
```

Which in turn, goes to a second php file that does this:

```
function get_Properties($currUser) {
    $mysql = New Mysql();
    return $mysql->get_Properties($currUser);   
}
```

And last but not least, that brings along the function I'm working on which is this:

```
function get_Properties($currUser) {
    //new instance of mysqli
        $mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
        //if it doesn't work give an error
        if (!$mysqli) {
            die('There was a problem connecting to the database.');
        }
        $queryProperties ="SELECT Id, Agent, MainImage, Address, Bedrooms, Baths, Price
                     FROM Properties
                     WHERE Agent = '$currUser'
                     ORDER BY Id DESC";
        if ($Results = $mysqli->query($queryProperties)){
            if (!$Results) {
                echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
                exit;
            }
            else{
                $Results = $mysqli->query($queryProperties);
            }
            while ($rows = $Results->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<div class="product clearfix">';
                  echo '<div class="l-image">';
                    echo '<img src="'.$rows['MainImage'].'" alt="'.$rows['Agent'].'" title="'.$rows['Agent'].'" />';
                    echo '<div class="l-image-hover">';
                      echo '<a href="#" class="l-lupa"><!-- --></a>';
                      echo '<a href="#" class="l-link"><!-- --></a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                 echo ' </div>';
                  echo '<div class="l-shadow"><!-- --></div>';
                  echo '<div class="l-title"><a href="property-details.php">'.$rows['Address'].'</a></div>';
                  echo '<div class="l-features clearfix">';
                    echo '<div class="l-bedrooms">'.$rows['Bedrooms'].' Bedrooms</div>';
                    echo '<div class="l-baths">'.$rows['Baths'].' Bathrooms</div>';
                  echo '</div>';
                  echo '<div class="l-details clearfix">';
                    echo '<div class="l-price">£'.$rows['Price'].' PCM</div>';
                    echo '<div class="l-view"><a href="property-details.php?PropertyId='.$rows['Id'].'">View details</a></div>';
                  echo '</div>';
                echo '</div>';
            }
        }
        $mysqli->close();
    }
}
```

Now the problem I am having - is that there isn't always going to be something to echo back. Sometimes the $rows variable will return nothing (no entries for that particular user).

The question is. How do I make it say "if no rows are returned, clearly there is no data for this user, so return a variable like $userHasNoData = 1. Or something like that. So that on the main page I can say "if (isset($userHasNoData)) { echo "no data!"; }

Oh, and as I am still learning, please feel utterly free to critique my code in any way to help me improve :) Thank you a bunch!

Comment: Your function is named wrong. It does not get anything and returns it, it prints stuff. While the function name does in now way affect execution, it is troublesome for all developers reading the code.

Comment: Hello Sven, sorry I can't see what you mean. Can you clarify for me? thank you

Comment: Your original function returns a value. That is the expected behaviour when commanding to "get_properties()". The second does not return anything, but prints it instead. It should be called "print_properties()". Or changed to return the properties.

Comment: Oh I see, so should that first line be: $mysql->get_Properties($currUser);  instead of return $mysql->get_Properties($currUser);  ?

Comment: No, the basic mistake is that your function uses `echo`. Don't do it there, do it somewhere else. Your function should return an array or object with the user properties, nothing else. If it does, you can elsewhere decide if you haven't found anything, and how this "nothing" should look like. If you don't return anything, you also cannot return `$userHasNoData=1`.

Comment: Oh yes I see. So I can return it as an array list and if so, do the relevant php/html on the main page. Thank you for the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on shannonoman's answer, you can add the [`num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php) call as a check before doing the while statement:

```
if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
    echo 'Sorry, no data!';
} else {
    while ($rows = $Results->fetch_assoc()) {
        // output stuff
    }
}
```

As an opportunity to further improve the code, I also want to point out you are calling `$mysqli->query` twice when you could do it once:

```
if ($Results = $mysqli->query($queryProperties)) {
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        echo 'Sorry, no data!';
    } else {
        while ($rows = $Results->fetch_assoc()) {
            // output stuff
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . $mysqli->error; // not mysql_error!
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the number of rows returned with:

```
$num_rows = $Results->num_rows;
```

So check that for zero and take whatever action you need.

Comment: Would that be within the confines of the function?
"$num_rows = $Results->num_rows;"
Or would that be on the page that calls the function? Or would I return $num_rows along with the echo?